# Prototype: call custom function after validation

Tags: javascript, validation, prototypejs

I'm using prototype and needs to call my function after succesfull validation.

Part of the code:

```
var validator  = new Validation(this.form);
```

this will validate the form, but I don't know how to call my function trackForm after the validation is correct and the form is submited.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I would need more details to answer, at least will try then.
I assume you're using PrototypeJS - the library. This lib does not support validation by default so you're probably using another library for that.

If you're using Dexagogo's validation (http://tetlaw.id.au/view/javascript/really-easy-field-validation) you will need to use onFormValidate callback.

I never used it, but presume you basically setup Validation like normally, with addition of that extra attribute. Like this:

```
var validator = new Validator(this.form, {onFormValidate: trackForm});
var trackForm = function (validationPassed, form) {
  if (validationPassed) {
    form.reset();
  }
}
```

*Ofc you don't need to create trackForm, but written as you mentioned about it.*

Hope this somewhat helps.

Answer (score -1):

I appreciate that the original question didn't mention the platform, but I found this question after Googling extensively for a solution on the Magento platform.

For those using Prototype through Magento and Magento's VarienForm, there's a simple way to do with without using any other validation libraries.

The validator is attached to the form when its initialised, and the onFormValidate method is an option on the validator.

You can access is as below:

```
this.form.validator.options.onFormValidate = function(validationPassed, form) {};
```

See the below example which I have tested for my own means and found it works exactly as expected:

```
var contactForm = new VarienForm('contactForm', true);
contactForm.validator.options.onFormValidate = function(validationPassed, form) {
    if(validationPassed){
         alert("Validation Passed");
    }
}
```